# Ember obeserve objects properties inside an array

Tags: ember.js

I have a question, i'm trying to observe object properties inside an array, but 'observes' don't work. How can i do this?

```
App.ArrayController = Em.Object.create({
array: [{foo:1}, {foo:2}, {foo:3}],
addElement: function() {
  this.array[0].foo = 5;
},
elementAdded: function() {
  alert('ok');
}.observes('array.@each')})
```

Here jsFiddle to show the problem: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8GFK2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problems in your code. This is the updated version:

```
// observes just work in the class so we need to use `extend`
App.ArrayController = Em.Object.extend({
    array: [
        // to be able to notify the view for 
        // the changes we need to use Ember.Object
        Ember.Object.create({foo:1}), 
        Ember.Object.create({foo:2}), 
        Ember.Object.create({foo:3})
    ],
    addElement: function() {        
        // Use the set('foo', 5) from Ember.Object to notify the observes, and rerender the template
        this.array.objectAt(0).set('foo', 5);
    },
    elementAdded: function() {
        alert('Ok')        
    }.observes('array.@each.foo') // array.@each.foo is required because you want to observe the change in the foo property of each element in array.
}).create() // with extend we create a class, so we need to create a instance using create method
```

And an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/B3We8/

Comment: Yeah,now i c, thanks. And how can i observe all properties in objects in an array?